# Delete data from two table in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables named Doctor and Users. The user table contain details about doctor, patient and admin. Doctor table contain details about doctors. These tables are linked to each other. I will get the id of the doctor to be deleted from the twig file. With that id i can delete data from Doctor table but how will i delete the data of same doctor in Users table? Can someone tell me the code.

Controller

```
public function doctorsAction(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if($id){
            $doctors = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Doctors')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->remove($doctors);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_doctors'));
       }
        $searchDate = $request->query->get('date');
        $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ProjectBundleBundle:Users')->findUserDoctor($request->query->get('search'), $searchDate);
        $form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), new Users());
        return array('doctors' => $results, 'form' => $form->createView(), 'searchDate' => ($searchDate ? $searchDate : date('Y-m-d')));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: the controller code?

Comment: yes. and relationsships between entites also. If you can.

Comment: the tables are related with their IDs. can you give me a code by using this concept? define getters by your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Doctrine's documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Use `cascade remove` on the relationship between Doctor and User.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an One-To-One ORM relation between Doctor and User objects with  cascade removing.

YouBundle\Entity\Doctor.php

```
     /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     */

     protected $user.
```